# Cross join problem with linq2sql

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql

I have the following LINQ2SQL query:

```
From pc In DBContext.ProcessCodes
Join c In DBContext.Cells On pc.idCell Equals c.idCell
    Where pc.idType = "Cars" AndAlso
          pc.Active = True AndAlso
          c.Active = True
    Select c
```

For some reason I am getting a cross join (cartesian product) when I think I should be getting an inner join.  I get the same thing if I do multiple From's with key comparison in the where.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your first step might be to check out the generated SQL.  http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2007/08/17/DataContextLogLoggingLINQToSQLOutputConsoleDebuggerOuputWindow.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think this help you:

```
From pc In DBContext.ProcessCodes 
From c In DBContext.Cells
Where pc.idType = "Cars" AndAlso           
      pc.Active = True AndAlso
      c.Active = True     
Select c
```